# reactjs event listener beforeunload added but not removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a react component like :

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'


class MyComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
       window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
            console.log("hellooww")
            event.returnValue = "Hellooww"
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
            console.log("hellooww")
            event.returnValue = "Hellooww"
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                Some content
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default MyComponent
```

Here event lister is added to the component. When I refresh the page it gives me pop up asking to leave the page.

But when I go to another page and do refresh it again shows the same pop-up.

I am removing the `eventListener` from the component on `componentWillUnmount`. Then why it is not being removed?

How can I remove the `beforeunload` event on other pages?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The `removeEventListener` should get the reference to the same callback that was assigned in `addEventListener`. Recreating the function won't do. The solution is to create the callback elsewhere (`onUnload` in this example), and pass it as reference to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';


class MyComponent extends Component {
    onUnload = e => { // the method that will be used for both add and remove event
       e.preventDefault();
       e.returnValue = '';
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Some content
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default MyComponent
```

### **React hooks**

You can abstract the `beforeunload` event handling to a custom hook with the `useRef`, and `useEffect` hooks.

The custom hook `useUnload` receives a function (`fn`) and assigns it to the current ref. It calls `useEffect` once (on component mount), and sets the event handler to be an anonymous function that will call `cb.current` (if it's [defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)), and returns a cleanup function to remove the event handler, when the component is removed.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const useUnload = fn => {
  const cb = useRef(fn); // init with fn, so that type checkers won't assume that current might be undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    cb.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onUnload = (...args) => cb.current?.(...args);

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onUnload);
  }, []);
};

export default useUnload;
```

**Usage:**

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  useUnload(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
  });

  return (
    <div>
      Some content
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Any idea why this works for refresh but not for going back?

Comment: It won't work if you're routing doesn't unload the component.

Comment: @OriDrori sure!

Comment: Thanks Its worked for me
Let me know how can we implement the same in tab close and back button

Comment: Here's a Typescript version: https://github.com/jacobbuck/react-beforeunload/issues/13

Answer (score 4):

Ori's solution didn't work for me.  I had to do this to make it work...  (Thank you docs)

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleLeavePage);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleLeavePage);
  }

  handleLeavePage(e) {
    const confirmationMessage = 'Some message';
    e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
    return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
  }
```

Comment: If you want to refer to your react component (this), change the second line to this.handleLeavePage.bind(this)

Comment: This only works on Chrome for me. Not firefox or safari.

Comment: Ah. Just so nobody makes the same mistake as I did at first - the confirmationMessage cannot be blank or no popup will appear. Now works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari

Answer (score 3):

You can use following hook:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beforeunload

Example:

```js
import { Beforeunload } from 'react-beforeunload';

// ...

<Beforeunload onBeforeunload={(event) => event.preventDefault()}>
  <MyApp />
</Beforeunload>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create same function and pass in   `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. When `returnValue` returns  a value other than null or undefined, the user will be prompted to confirm the page unload.

```
 import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
    
    
    class MyComponent extends Component {
        beforeUnLoad = e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          e.returnValue = "leave";
    
      };
    
        componentDidMount() {
           window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.beforeUnLoad)
        }
    
        componentWillUnmount() {
            window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.beforeUnLoad)
        }
    
        render() {
    
            return (
                <div>
                    Some content
                </div>
            )
        }
    
    }
    
    export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

hooks/FC answer:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

 const beforeUnLoad = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.returnValue = '';
 }
    
 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnLoad);
  
   return () => {
     window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnLoad);
   };
 }, []);

 return <>Hello World</>
}
```