# Detect window close on React

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a SCORM  course using React and I must detect when user closes the tab to send the correct event to Lms

I tried to search for similar questions, and even following the answers of this thread [reactjs event listener beforeunload added but not removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094138/reactjs-event-listener-beforeunload-added-but-not-removed) I could not make it work, onbeforeunload is just not called.

Also componentwillunmount do not works when user closes the window directly.

Any suggestions about how I could achieve this?

Comment: componentWillUnmount will never work if the user closes the window. Though the beforeunload event should trigger.

Comment: ok, so i am in the good track, but struggling to make it work. i will try to update the question with a example.

Comment: Maybe similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094138/reactjs-event-listener-beforeunload-added-but-not-removed

Comment: In fact, it was working but the way I was testing wasn't good.